# Google Maps iOS - Move marker on top of view

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm creating an application with `google maps` and `custom markers`. What I want to do is: when I select a marker, I want to display a gray background with transparency on top of the `map` and move the `marker` on top of this background.

The problem I'm having is, setting the `zIndex` of the marker higher than `zIndex` of the background doesn't work, and `iconView` is always `nil` when the `delegate` recognizes touch on a `marker`.

Any ideas how to achieve/do it?

Right now my approach is:

I added a subview to my map view with the effect I want, when the `delegate` recognizes touch I animate it to appear and try to move my marker on top of it.

Comment: any luck @Guilherme

Comment: @nikdange_me I'm trying some outcomes here, the closest I managed to achieve was:
when a `marker` is tapped, I translate it's `position` to screen coordinates and place a new `UIImageView` on top of everything at that screen position.
I'm still looking for a better solution.